# ASP.NET Parallel Web Service Calls

Tags: c#, service, parallel-processing, concurrency

I have an aspx page which reads items from an SQL DB and displays them on a GridView.
For every item located in DB there are several metadata associated with it which can be retrieved by making a Web Service call per item in the GridView.
What I want to do is to make concurrent calls to the web-service (in order to save time from sequential calls) and fill these metadata in the GridView.
Any ideas ?

Thank you,
Dimitris

Comment: Are you trying to do this before sending the data to the client? Or would you be willing to do this on the client side with Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you have 2 options. One would be to use client side ajax to fetch the data after the page has loaded. The other option would be to use an asynchronous httpwebrequest and fetch the data before the page loads.

If possible given your security requirements as well as functionality requirements, I think ajax is the better way to go. It will put less load on your servers.

To elaborate:
After your page loads, if possible, have the client call the webservice directly, completely bypassing your servers. This is likely to be the fastest *seeming* option, especially if you have many items to get data for. The first few will load quickly, and the user won't notice that the rest are loading while they are busy with the first few.

Alternately, if security is an issue (your webservice has credentials you don't want the world to know), you might want to proxy off your server, having your server return the results from the webservice, which the client asks for via ajax.

Comment: Hello again,
I think that it my case it would be better to make server side Asynchronous Calls. Since I don't know the exact number of calls could you provide a sample on how to call n times Asynchronously the string WebMethodX(strin sInputXML)?
Thank You,
Dimitris.